# Center a stack of div's CSS

Tags: html, css, centering

I am trying to stack a `div` on top of a `div` and center those two `div`s horizontally in the page.

```css
.sandBox{
  position:relative;
}
.product-image, .option-image{
  position:absolute;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}
.product-image{
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<div class="sandBox">
  <div class="product-image">
    <img src="main-product-image.jpg" width="1440" height="560" alt=""/>
  </div>

  <div class="option-image">
    <img src="overlay.png" width="1440" height="560" alt=""/>
  </div>
</div>
```

This stack part works fine but I can not seem to get them centered no mater what I try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should make them centered.

```
.product-image, .option-image{
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    left: 0; /*NEW*/
    right: 0; /*NEW*/
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/hno8bxty/

Comment: Don’t forget to set `max-width:100%;` on certain things, because not everyone has a 1440px wide screen.

Comment: That worked, but I had to also add text-align: center to .sandbox. - Thanks!

Comment: Great tip! it's not necessary to add text-align, but it won't hurt either.